# Why is Module.DEFAULT_REFLECTOR not initialized?

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-pub, dart2js

This is an Angular 1.0 application. The error in Chrome's console is:

```
Uncaught Module.DEFAULT_REFLECTOR not initialized for dependency injection.http://goo.gl/XFXx9G
```

I've read the other posts, and I do have the Angular transformer in my pubspec.yaml:

```yml
dependencies:
  barback: any
  browser: any
  angular: 1.0.0
  msgpack:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/danellis/dart-msgpack.git
      ref: master
dev_dependencies:
  template_cache_transformer: any
threadsafe: yes
transformers:
  - $dart2js:
      environment:
        MIRRORS: 'false'
  - angular:
      html_files:
        - lib/templates/app.html
        - lib/templates/input.html
        - lib/templates/roster.html
        - lib/templates/space.html
        - lib/templates/space_list.html
        - lib/templates/alerts.html
        - lib/templates/rostermenu.html
  - template_cache_transformer:
      entry_point: webatara|templates/app.html
```

My main function looks like this:

```dart
void main() {
    applicationFactory().addModule(new WebataraModule()).run();
}
```

After a `pub build`, the modified main.dart has this in it:

```dart
void main() {
  setStaticReflectorAsDefault();
    staticApplicationFactory(generated_static_metadata.typeAnnotations, generated_static_expressions.getters, generated_static_expressions.setters, generated_static_expressions.symbols, generated_static_type_to_uri_mapper.typeToUriMapper).addModule(new WebataraModule()).run();
}
```

`setStaticReflectorAsDefault` does this:

```dart
setStaticReflectorAsDefault() => Module.DEFAULT_REFLECTOR = new GeneratedTypeFactories(typeFactories, parameterKeys);
```

So it would seem that Module.DEFAULT_REFLECTOR does get set. So why the error?

Comment: What does the `threadsafe` setting do? Never heard of such a setting for `pubspec.yaml`. I know what it does in `app.yaml` though.

Comment: Good question. I believe DartEditor put it there right at the beginning of the project.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback. I wonder why no tool complains about it if it is not valid. I assume it isn't because Dart has no threads. If it is in fact valid it should be documented somewhere. I'll keep my eyes open ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transformers are applied in the order listed in the transformers section. $dart2js should always be the last and `template_cache_transformer` should probably come before `angular`.

Comment: Oh. That might be a problem. My entry page is in an entirely different project.

Comment: How can the entry page be a entirely different project. I think in this case you should add the transformer to the project containing the entry page and also build this project.

Comment: It's in a non-Dart project. I'll see if I can transfer it over.

Comment: I didn't read your `pubspec.yaml` properly. I missed that the `entry_point` is a different transformer. Have you tried to change the order of the transformers? Normally `$dart2js` should be last and maybe `template_cache_transformer` should come before `angular` (not sure, I'm not using Angular since a while). There was a change recently to make it less a problem when `$dart2js` is not the last transformer, but I don't know exactly what the change was (maybe just a proper error message instead of a fail).